# Creating Emulator Profile for Galaxy mini s4 in AVD

Tags: android

Can Anyone explain how can i create Galaxy S4 mini profile in AVD New Defintion ?

Device Spec in this site :

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9190_galaxy_s4_mini-5375.php

are like this :

540 x 960 pixels,

4.3 inches (~256 ppi pixel density)

1.5 GB RAM Internal Memory

now how can i find out exact value for :

screen Size : ?

size (size-normal-large-xlarge) : ?

Screen Ratio (Long-Notlong) : ?

Density (XXhdpi-xhdpi-hdpi-tvdpi-mdpi-ldpi-nodpi) : ?

and what layout folder should i create for This emulator or device in res ?

(layout-960x540 , layout-sw600dp or layout-sw720dp ) ?

i have Created these layouts in my program :

[image]

Now problem is i dont own This device , for other device i use this method to get The bucket folder :

```
View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.layouttype);
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Layout Bucket is : "+ v.getTag().toString());
```

and adding "layouttype" in each master layout in folders.

Comment: for negative point , Is this question unclear or not useful? should i add more hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the emulator by the following method

1. Window> AVD Manager>Device Definitions
2. Clone any of the device in the list
3. Edit the cloned Device enter the following info:
   Name: Galaxy S4 Mini
   Screen Size: 4.3
   Resolution: 540x960 
   Density: hdpi (Note: when you enter the pixels Density is auto adjusted)
4. Tap Edit Device and Quit Eclipse.
5. Download the S4 miniskin from here
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-emulator-skins/files/
6. Place it under sdk/platform/android-17/skins/
7. Restart Eclipse Go to AVD Manager choose Galaxy S4 min, set Android Target to 17, and choose the downloaded skin.
8. Press Start!.